# Multiselect picklist's Selected Values are not getting reset on Instantiate Object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, visualforce-component, picklist

I have 2 vf pages, On first page the values which has been selected by user need to be remained in second vf page.

On second page values of two fields are disable user can't make selection of it.
Problem:
I have used 1 multi select picklist(Standard) field.
On click of reset button the value of this multiselect picklist should reseted.
In controller I have use PageRefernce method for Reset , In that I am Instantiating object whose fields needs to be reset.  values of the other field are getting reset but Value selecteed in multiselect picklist is not getting reset.

Comment: Can you post you VF code where you have the reference to this field and Apex code for Rest method!!

Comment: public pagereference Reset(){
       
        wrapper_Observation obj = new wrapper_Observation();
        wRisk=new Risk__c();
        wObservation=new Observation__c();
        return null;
    }